Two different versions of Newton's Third Law
I have two different versions of Newton's Third Law.

Newton's Law is simply a way of describing forces. When a moving Object A, hits Object B and transfers all its energy to B, Object A stops because of the opposite force my object B causes it to decelerate. If object A puts a force of 10N on Object B, then Object A gains 10 N. While Object B becomes 0 because of 10-10. But if the thing that put energy, isnt motion, then it will move back. This means that when an object hits the ground it bounces not because of newtons law, because its momentum is reversed. this fits in with conversation of momentum. However this doesnt make sense with why rocket would work using this law. The same amount of force that the rocket pushes on is minused so it shouldnt move.

Newton's Law indeed means that when Object A hits Object B, it transfers all its energy to Object B so it starts moving with the same speed as Object A, but Object b gains the same accceleration and it speeds double. This is why when a ball hits the ground it reflects back because of the reaction energy from the ground. It make sense that when you push a wall you feel force, and why you feel pain when you hit something. This make sense with pushing yourself in swimming pool and rockets. However this means that the force is doubled so this cant be true.


I am confused because everybody has a different version of the law.To me 1 is the better version. But it doesnt make sense when you think about why balls bounce.

“When a moving Object A, hits Object B and transfers all its energy to B,” that only applies if (a) the objects have the same mass and (b) the collision is perfectly elastic.

“If object A puts a force of 10N on Object B, then Object A gains 10 N. While Object B becomes 0 because of 10-10.”. Objects don’t gain or lose force. They gain or lose energy and momentum.  The Newton 3rd law forces don’t cancel each other. They act on different objects.

“This means that when an object hits the ground it bounces not because of newtons law, because its momentum is reversed. this fits in with conversation of momentum.” Momentum is conserved only because the earth moves (imperceptibly) in the opposite direction to the object.

Recognize that you have hidden assumptions regarding how physics works.  Try to recognize those hidden assumptions.  Also, listen carefully to your physics teacher, work quite a few physics problems, and do your best to unlearn those hidden assumptions and learn correct physics concepts.


... everybody has a different version of the law.

No they don't. There is essentially only one version of Newton's Third Law, which is:

If two bodies exert forces on each other, these forces have the same magnitude but opposite directions.

There may be minor variations of wording in different sources, but they will all amount to the same thing. Your two "versions" are your own interpretations of Newton's Third Law, both of which are faulty because you are confusing the concepts of force, momentum and energy.

When a moving Object A, hits Object B and transfers all its energy to B, Object A stops because the opposite force  Object B causes it to decelerate.

More or less correct, although specifically what is transferred is kinetic energy, and you are describing a particular scenario in which A and B have equal masses. If A and B have masses $m_A$ and $m_B$, A has initial velocity $u$ and $B$ is initially at rest then the velocity of $A$ after the collision is
$\displaystyle v = u \left( \frac {m_A-m_B} {m_A+m_B} \right)$
So you can see that $v=0$ only if $m_A = m_B$.

If object A puts a force of 10N on Object B, then Object A gains 10 N.

No. Force acts on an object, but (unlike momentum and energy) it is not an attribute of an object, it is not transferred from one object to another, and it is not conserved.

... when an object hits the ground it bounces not because of newtons law, because its momentum is reversed.

When an object A hits the ground B, we can treat $m_B$, the mass of the Earth, as being effectively infinite (bouncing a ball is not going have any measurable affect on the Earth). Applying the equation above we have
$v = -u$
i.e. after the collision the velocity of the bouncing object is reversed (this assumes that the collision is perfectly elastic i.e. there is no loss of energy). This is just as much a consequence of Newton's Third Law and conservation of momentum as is your first scenario.

... when Object A hits Object B, it transfers all its energy to Object B so it starts moving with the same speed as Object A, but Object B gains the same acceleration and its speed doubles.

Sorry, I have no idea what you are trying to say in this sentence.

... this means that the force is doubled so this can't be true.

You seem to be assuming that force is somehow conserved - but this not not correct. During the collision, object A exerts a force on object B. This force may vary over the duration of the collision, but at any point in time Newton's Third Law tells us that object B is exerting a force on A that is equal in size but opposite in direction to the force exerted by A on B. Although the size of the force may vary during the collision, if we integrate the force exerted by A on B over the duration of the the collision (which we call the impulse exerted by A on B) then we get the change in momentum of object B (because of Newton's First Law) - let's call this $\Delta p_B$. However, Newton's Third Law tells us that if we integrate the force exerted by B on A to get the change in momentum of object A, $\Delta p_A$, then this must have the same magnitude but the opposite sign to $\Delta p_B$. In other words $\Delta p_A = - \Delta p_B$, so $\Delta p_A + \Delta p_B=0$, and this is conservation of momentum.
In practice, when analysing collisions, we do not usually worry about trying to work out the exact forces involved and how they vary over time - we just go straight to conservation of momentum and conservation of energy.

I think that you got the wrong idea about N3L as it is not to do with energy.
In simple terms N3L states that the force on body $A$ due to body $B$, $\vec F_{\rm AB}$,  is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the force on body $B$ due to body $A$, , $\vec F_{\rm BA}$, ie  $\vec F_{\rm AB} = - \vec F_{\rm BA}$.
If the two bodies for a system and there are no forces coming from outside the system and the time the bodies interact is $\Delta t$ then the impulse on body $A$ due to body $B$ is $\vec F_{\rm AB}\Delta t$ and the impulse on body $B$ due to body $A$ is $\vec F_{\rm BA}\Delta t$, ie $\vec F_{\rm AB}\Delta t = - \vec F_{\rm BA}\Delta t$.
Now impulse is equal to change in momentum (N2L) so the change of momentum of body $A$ is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the change in momentum of body $B$ leading to the fact that the overallchange of momentum for the two bodies is zero, which is the law of conservation of momentum.
Notice that there has been no mention of energy.
As an example However this doesn't make sense with why rocket would work using this law. The same amount of force that the rocket pushes on is misused so it shouldn't move.
System rocket and fuel and no external forces.
Force on burning fuel due to rocket changes the momentum of the burning fuel in one direction and the force on the rocket due to the burning fuel changes the momentum of the rocket by the same amount but in the opposite direction.
Overall there is no net change in the momentum of the rocket and the burning fuel.
Another example, This is why when a ball hits the ground it reflects back because of the reaction energy from the ground.
System ball and Earth including ground and no external forces.
Force on ball due to Earth changes the momentum of the ball in one direction and the force on the Earth due to the ball changes the momentum of the Earth by the same amount but in the opposite direction.
Overall there is no net change in the momentum of the ball and the Earth.
You only notice the change in velocity (momentum) of the ball because the Earth is so massive as compared with the ball its velocity changes imperceptibly.
